# Will multilingual content on same page works to avoid content duplication

Tags: google-search-console, duplicate-content, googlebot, ranking

We have a website, which is having old/new vehicle deals for purchase.

We are getting these data from third party website (legally) and all the pages are in English language.

So, Here our issue is content duplication. The data of our web pages are already there on many pages (from where we are getting), before we published them.

So somehow to distinguish the content, we planned to put vehicle description (Around 1 paragraph of 3-4 lines) in French on every page.

Our sole purpose to avoid content duplication as Google gives important & good ranking to unique content  pages.

With this approach, will Google identify that our content is some what different ?

I can provide more details if required.

Answer (score 3):

> **So somehow to distinguish the content, we planned to put vehicle description (Around 1 paragraph of 3-4 lines) in French on every page.**

If your website and third-party content are in English, adding a few lines of French will only create a bad user experience and confuse Google as covered [here](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/182192?hl=en#1):

> Google uses only the visible content of your page to determine its
>   language. We don’t use any code-level language information such as
>   lang attributes. You can help Google determine the language correctly
>   by using a single language for content and navigation on each page,
>   and by avoiding side-by-side translations. Translating only the
>   boilerplate text of your pages while keeping the bulk of your content
>   in a single language (as often happens on pages featuring
>   user-generated content) can create a bad user experience if the same
>   content appears multiple times in search results with various
>   boilerplate languages.

Therefore you should create a [multilingual](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/182192?hl=en) version of your site for other languages and not mix them in the same page.

> **Our sole purpose to avoid content duplication as Google gives important & good ranking to unique content pages.**

Google ranks pages that contain good and relevant content,  among other criteria - not just unique.

> **With this approach, will Google identify that our content is some what different?**

Not likely. Try supplying a fair amount of English content around the data that's relevant to it, and apply good SEO practices towards your other pages to drive traffic to them and your site.

Answer (score 2):

Duplicated content is fine with Google when:

- It isn't stolen
- It is properly attributed
- It isn't the majority of the content on the site
- The site adds value to the duplicated content
- **Users find it useful**

Google doesn't like:

- [Pages with mixed languages](http://climbtothestars.org/archives/2008/08/09/google-dont-mix-languages-on-the-same-page/)
- Tricks to try to deceive Google into thinking a site is better or more unique than it is
- Sites that don't have original content or which don't add value to content that they syndicate
- Sites that have poor user experience.

Your plan is foolhardy.  Google is likely to de-index your site within a matter of months.

You should:

- Keep your site all in English
- Ensure that you have enough original content (80% original would be ideal)
- Don't let Googlebot crawl pages with little original content (use robots.txt or meta noindex)
- Focus Googlebot's attention on pages where your site adds value to syndicated content (where you have customer reviews, additional information, or analysis that is unique to your site)